# Digit sum formula $n - 9 \sum_{i\ge1} \left \lfloor \frac{n}{10^i} \right \rfloor$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

Let $S(n)$ be the sum of digits of n

Prove that $S(n) = n  -  9 \sum_{i\ge 1} \left \lfloor \frac{n}{10^i} \right \rfloor$ for all natural numbers n

I started with induction which works easily if $10$ doesn't divide $n+1$, because then $S(n+1)$ is just $S(n) + 1$.

However, if $10|(n+1)$ then $S(n+1)$ could be anything. Moreover, I have no idea how to use that fact.
If I write e.g. $n = 10k + 9$ then $\sum_{i\ge1} \left \lfloor \frac{10k+10}{10^i} \right \rfloor$ = $\sum_{i\ge1} \left \lfloor \frac{k+1}{10^{i-1}} \right \rfloor$  and I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Maybe it would help to use strong induction, then for the $10\mid (n+1)$ case, use the digit sum formula for $S\left(\frac{n+1}{10}\right)$.

Comment: One fun thing about a result like this is that it seems potentially completely useless, as the formula seems much more tedious than simply adding the digits. Perhaps it has some meaning when one is programming a method to take care of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using strong induction, assume for all $n = 1,2, \ldots, k$, the sum of digits formula holds:

$$S(n) = n - 9\sum_{i\ge 1} \left\lfloor\frac n{10^i}\right\rfloor$$

The induction step would be to prove that $S(k+1)$ follows the same formula.

For the cases that $10\mid (k+1)$, let $k+1 = 10q$, (and so $1\le q \le k$)

$$\begin{align*}
S(k+1) &= S\left(\frac{k+1}{10}\right)\\
&= S(q)\\
&= q - 9\sum_{i\ge 1} \left\lfloor\frac q{10^i}\right\rfloor\\
&= \frac{k+1}{10} - 9 \sum_{i\ge 1} \left\lfloor\frac {(k+1)/10}{10^i}\right\rfloor\\
&= 10\cdot\frac{k+1}{10}-9\cdot\frac{k+1}{10} - 9 \sum_{j\ge 2} \left\lfloor\frac {k+1}{10^j}\right\rfloor && (j=i+1)\\
&= (k+1) - 9 \sum_{j\ge 1} \left\lfloor\frac {k+1}{10^j}\right\rfloor\\
&= RHS
\end{align*}$$

For the other cases that $10\not\mid(k+1)$, OP already mentioned in the question that $S(k+1) = S(k)+1$.

---

It is possible to merge the two cases with a slight change, by also proving the base case $n=0$ and including it into the assumption.

For the $n=k+1$ case, let $k+1 = 10q + r$, where $q = \left\lfloor \dfrac{k+1}{10}\right\rfloor$ and $r=(k+1)\bmod 10$.

$$\begin{align*}
S(k+1) &= S(q) + r\\
&= q - 9\sum_{i\ge 1} \left\lfloor\frac q{10^i}\right\rfloor + r\\
&= q - 9\sum_{i\ge 1} \left\lfloor\frac {10q/10}{10^i}\right\rfloor + r\\
&= 10q - 9\cdot \frac{10q}{10} - 9\sum_{j\ge 2} \left\lfloor\frac {10q}{10^j}\right\rfloor + r&&(j=i+1)\\
&= 10q - 9\sum_{j\ge 1} \left\lfloor\frac {10q}{10^j}\right\rfloor + r\\
&= 10q+r - 9\sum_{j\ge 1} \left\lfloor\frac {10q}{10^j} + \frac{r}{10^j}\right\rfloor\\
&= (k+1) - 9\sum_{j\ge 1} \left\lfloor\frac {k+1}{10^j}\right\rfloor\\
&= RHS
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be given and let $10^k$ be the largest power of $10$ that divides $n+1$. Then we have:
$$
n=a+10^k d-1
$$
where $a$ is divisible by $10^{k+1}$ and $d\in\{1, 2,\cdots,9\}$. Now clearly:
$$
S(n)=S(a)+S(10^k d-1)
$$
similarly we have:
$$
S(n+1)=S(a)+S(10^k d)
$$
This shows that it suffices to focus on the latter part, so all you need is success for the induction step with $n+1=10^k d$. Thus we check:
$$
\begin{align}
10^k d-9\sum_{i\geq 1}\left\lfloor\frac{10^k d}{10^i}\right\rfloor
&=d\left(10^k-9(1+10+...+10^{k-1})\right)\\
&=d\left(10^k-(10^k - 1)\right)\\
&=d\\
&=S(10^k d)
\end{align}
$$
which is all we need to take care of all the steps in your original induction that were not covered.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$n=\sum_{k=0}^m \lambda_k\cdot 10^k$$
Then $$S(n)=\sum_{k=0}^m \lambda_k$$
and $$\bigg\lfloor \frac{n}{10^i} \bigg\rfloor=\sum_{k=0}^{m-i}\lambda_{k+i}\cdot 10^k$$
So we are proving that: $$\sum_{k=0}^m \lambda_k\cdot 10^k-\sum_{k=0}^m \lambda_k=9\sum_{i=1}^m \bigg(\sum_{k=0}^{m-i}\lambda_{k+i}\cdot 10^k\bigg)$$

It seems quite nice from here.